# Cross-polarization viewing from different angles are not consistent?

Tags: optics, reflection, polarization

I'm trying to utilize cross-polarization to eliminate reflections on objects in photography. I use linear polarizing filters on multiple light sources (polarized lights are my only light sources, no bounce lights) and a circular polarizer filter (CPL) on the camera lens to achieve cross-polarization.

I've lined everything perfectly so there are no reflection on even somewhat glossy objects. After that I start to move the camera on the vertical plane (up and down) and tilting the aim angle to aim at the object, I don't move the lights, only the camera.

Here are the issues I ran into when I do so:

1. When I changed the camera heights, I lost the cross-polarization. If I rotate the CPL, it will only get some lights into the cross-polarization, not all of them. I thought the polarization will offset by the same amount when viewing from different angle, but it seems they are offset by different amount. Why?
2. When I start to rotate the object on a turntable (it is not perfectly centered, so it will rotate off the vertical axis ), I lose cross-polarization on some lights, which light to lose the cross-polarization depending on the rotation of the subject. Why and how to avoid?

I would like to know how polarization of light works/oriented when being reflected in different surfaces with different surface normals and how to solve my above issues, with different camera height/angles but the same lights. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you thought of asking this in the photography stack exchange? I would say, from a physics point of view there might be many many possible reasons for what you are seeing.

Comment: @JoséAndrade I did ask a similar but different-purposed question in the photography stack exchange, I feel like I will get different perspectives from different community where the focuses are different. Here I hope I can get some explanations that help me to better understand the physics behind it, so that I can be more flexible when solving polarization issues.